# Node.JS mysql populating a class

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, pdo

Hi so i just thought of this don't really know if i can ask this here but i need help

How will i use Node.JS to populate a class or function i don't see why Node wouldn't have this since you need a database for WebDev and server side it makes things a lot easier

Example in PHP you can use PDO::FETCH_CLASS

```
$Data = $this->DB->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
$Data->execute();
$Data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'UserDatas');
```

How can i do this in Node.JS i tried google couldn't find any help...

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of package for nodejs for example [node-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql) . a lot of node guys use this npm package

But i prefer [sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/) , this will give you migration feature along with seeding feature , you can have laravel like taste in it

Comment: Can you give me an example of populating a class with sequelizejsi i am interested in sequelizejs

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/

check this out @Wexo .. there are a lot in the documentation , please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can. Check the docs of [node-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql) for instance.

Comment: if it does the populating can you give an example please?